# Can you unstack a calculated column from the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi guys fairly new to asking questions here.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
```

df = pd.read_csv('Tme of Day_Report_90 Days_1.csv')

```
df['CPA'] = df['Revenue (Adv Currency)']/df['Total Conversions']
```

This gives me:

Out[458]: df

[image: Data and Calculated column 'CPA' by time of day]

My next code to reshape the data

## Retructuring data

```
new_data = df.groupby(['Time','Day of Week']).mean()['CPA'].unstack()
```

## Rearranging columns by day of week

```
 new_data = new_data[['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']]
```

I'm trying to unstack the output into this form shown below. i'm not sure if using mean() and unstack the column while aggregating a calculated metric in this case **'CPA'** would lead to inaccurate values. Any advise on how to aggreggate the calculated column in the unstacked final form shown below is appreciated!

[image: Time of Day by Hour Table]

Sorry not sure how to paste data in tables so have it in image.

Comment: Give the simplest example and reproduce the error.

Comment: thanks for your help! not sure why we would use reset index here? i'm actually worried the averaging of the CPA column calculated based on dividing 2 other columns in the original df would be an average of an average when we do a group by.

Comment: I think my question was not worded well, no errors run into but afraid if I do a group by the output shown above would be inaccurate - does that make more sense?

Comment: @Jon just do `df.to_clipboard()` to copy the dataframe to your clipboard. See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html)